# Background Image for Main Section

Tags: css, reactjs, web-frontend, chakra-ui

I'm writing a React web application and I also use Chakra-UI. In general, I have a header, main section and a footer. Like this

https://jsfiddle.net/7cmasxLq/

```
<div id="header">
  header
</div>

<div id="main">
  Main
</div>

<div id="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

and

```
#header {
  background-color: red;
}

#main {
  background-image: url('https://www.epfl.ch/schools/ic/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/EPFL-aerial-Rolex-towards-East-1920x1080.jpg');
}

#footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

So the header is always at the top and the footer is always at the bottom.

Now for the landing page, I'd like to add a background image that spans the space between the header and the footer but I'm unsure what the best approach is, especially when using Chakra-UI.

In my example, I use background-image but I've read that one should rather use an image element but in the light of me using Chakra-UI, it's even more confusing.

What is a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example in the chakra-ui playground: [play.chakra-ui.com](https://play.chakra-ui.com/playground?code=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)

So, you can use the Box component as main building block for header, main and footer. Also, you can add a background image to the Box.

```
import { Button, Box } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export const App = () => {
   return (
    <Box display="grid" gridTemplateRows="auto 1fr auto" minHeight="100vh">
      <Box id="header" bg="red">
        Header
      </Box>

      <Box
        id="main"
        bgImage="url('https://www.epfl.ch/schools/ic/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/EPFL-aerial-Rolex-towards-East-1920x1080.jpg')"
        bgSize="cover"
        bgPosition="center"
      >
        <Box>Main</Box>
      </Box>

      <Box id="footer" bg="yellow" py="10px" position="fixed" left="0" bottom="0" width="100%" textAlign="center">
        Footer
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that set the minHeight explicitly, leading to a vertical scrolling. One would had to compute the hight as basically `minHeight="calc(100vh - 10px - heightOfHeader)"`.  Note that now we also would have to set the height of the header eplicitly. Can I avoid that?

Comment: Ok, I slightly changed the solution, check it out. Just use grid template rows to avoid setting heights.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Chakra specific, but the problem is that your main content isn't filling the space - it's only as tall as the content within it.

To get it to stretch and fill the space you could use flexbox:

```css
body, html {
  /* Remove any margins so wrapper takes all space */
  margin: 0; 
}
.wrapper {
  /* full height the wrapper, and flex col so it's vertical */
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  /* flex-grow the content so it takes any empty space in the wrapper */
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>

</div>
```

as for your background-or-image question, i prefer to use backgrounds in this case - that's what this is at the end of the day! plus, if the background doesn't load in you don't end up with an ugly broken image icon appearing

Comment: Why use a wrapper? Why not apply it directly to the body?

Comment: you can apply it straight to the body if that works for you & your designs, just move the wrapper css onto the body